# Nginx Http redirect to https actually not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, https, passenger, http-redirect

So, I have this setup under my nginx **sites-available** file.

```
passenger_pre_start http://my_site;

log_format access_with_host '$remote_addr/$http_x_forwarded_for [$time_iso8601] $host '
                    '"$request" $status in [$request_time] $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_site my_site_alias_1 my_site_alias_2;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    root /home/ubuntu/apps/sites/current/public/;

    rails_env production;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_min_instances 20;

    gzip on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;

    access_log  /home/ubuntu/apps/sites/shared/log/access.log access_with_host;
    error_log  /home/ubuntu/apps/sites/shared/log/error.log error;
```

So, I want to redirect http to https BUT after adding these 3 lines

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
 return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

I am getting a **Error: Too many redirects**. That doesn't make sense since the http is actually redirected to https but I can't see the site at all, just the browser window with the previous legend.

Any help would be really appreciated to fix this!

Comment: Where is the server that accepts `https` connections? If it's a reverse proxy in front of this one, is it setting the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header?

Comment: Please add the server block that serves HTTPS requests too.